# Finding the Determinant of a particular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, problem-solving

I've come across the question of finding the determinant of the $(n\times n)$ matrix, given by

$$A:=
\begin{pmatrix}
x & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
1 & x & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
\vdots && \ddots &  & \vdots \\
1  & \dots  & \dots & x & 1\\ 
1 &\dots & \dots & 1&x^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

for all $x \in \mathbb R$ and for all $n\geq2$. I know that the answer is $$\det A =(x-1)^{n-1} \cdot (x^2+(n-1) x+n-1) \tag 1$$

and I can prove it by induction if I'm allow to make some hand-wavy assumptions, which I'm not allowed to do because it was an exam question of a pure maths class (linear algebra). However I think that I'm missing something because without having a computer algebra system, coming up with the equation $(1)$ is hard enough, let alone the two inductions I need to do in order to show the equation $(1)$ with some hand-wavy assumptions, which makes the question way too hard for a 2 hour exam.

Is there an easier way to calculate this determinant?

Comment: Should the last diagonal entry be an $x^2$?

Comment: Yes only the last diagonal is $x^2$ the rest of the diagonal is $x$ and everywhere else is $1$.

Comment: One nice approach is to note that this matrix is a rank-1 update of a relatively nice matrix (the one with only $x$s on the diagonal).

Comment: Yeah but I've given some thought on that but nothing seems to come up...

Comment: Hint to a different answer than @user2373145's: Do you know how to compute the determinant of the same matrix but with an $x$ instead of the $x^2$ ? Now reduce your problem to this simpler one, by Laplace expanding along the last row.

Answer (score 1):

You add up all the rows to the first one giving x + n-1 for all but the n-th element, which is x² + n-1.

Then you factor out the x + n-1 (with the condition that it isn't zero, prove the trivial case separately; the general solution also holds for x=-n+1), so the first row becomes all ones except for the n-th entry.

Then you subtract the first row from all the others getting an upper triangular matrix with a (1, x-1, ..., x-1, x²-(x²+n-1)/(x+n-1)) main diagonal.

Now the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the elements in its main diagonal.

So we have detAₙ = (x+n-1) (x-1)^(n-2) (x²-(x²+n-1)/(x+n-1)) = (x−1)^(n−1) (x²+(n−1)x+n−1).

Comment: You could treat this calculation as being over the field $\mathbb R(x)$, so $x+n-1$ is definitively non-zero :)

Comment: @Erick Wong could you elaboraborate a bit more on that?

Comment: Sure... first of all I'm just saying there are other ways to justify the same calculation that don't require explicitly checking $x=-n+1$ separately.  One is to interpret the elements of the matrix as being elements of the field of rational functions $\mathbb R(x)$, so that the element $x+n-1$ is a polynomial of degree $1$, not the zero element.  Note also that the LHS is necessarily a polynomial in $x$, and so is the RHS, and they agree at infinitely many values of $x$, so they must agree for all $x$.